# Link component with nextjs doesnt work (not clickable ?)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Working on some web site draft,

I have an issue that I dont understand
None of my < Link > are clickable. I use nextjs link component,
by inspecting my page I seems that everything is generate as expected

```
<Link href={`/about/about-dark`}>
    <a
     className="butn bord curve mt-40 wow fadeInUp"
     data-wow-delay=".8s"
>
      <span>Discover</span>
    </a>
</Link>
```

It's even more weird because the link in my menu works, but none of my buttons does.

here a demo: https://main.d3jahvwbjvsmfk.amplifyapp.com/

Comment: And also if you down below answer is not work for you then add your code in online editors like ***codesandbox*** for better understanding